# Show posts' usernames in ejs

Tags: node.js, mongoose, ejs

I'm making my first Node.js app with an ejs view engine. I have two models: post and user. I've tried linking these two models together but can't seem to figure out how to show what user posted what post!

This is the user model:

```
// User Schema
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        index:true
    },
    password: {
        type: String
    },
    email: {
        type: String
    },
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    facebook : {
            id           : String,
            token        : String
        },
    posts : [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post' }]
});
```

This is the post:

```
// Post Schema
var PostSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    user: {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    name: {
        type: String,
        index:true
    },
    text: {
        type: String
    }
});
```

This is my controller/route to show posts:

```
// Post page
router.get('/post', function(req, res){
    req.db.collection('posts').find().toArray((err, result) => {
        if (err) return console.log(err)
        res.render('posts/post', {posts: result, req: req});
    })  
});
```

## Now

If I have this in my view file (ejs):

```
<%posts.forEach(function(element){%>
        <li>
            <%=element.name%> <br>
            <%=element.text%> <br>
            <%=element.user.username %>
        </li>
        <br>
 <%});%>
```

I get the output of "username" to be "undefined"

If I put this instead:

```
<%posts.forEach(function(element){%>
        <li>
            <%=element.name%> <br>
            <%=element.text%> <br>
            <%=element.user %>
        </li>
        <br>
 <%});%>
```

I get the username as: d6cf225e (my user id).

Why can't I retrieve my username from by just adding ".username"? When I add a new post it seems like all the information is there. In my console I can see the following message being inserted:

```
{ __v: 0,
 name: 'lol',
 text: 'test',
 user: 
  { _id: d6cf225e,
    username: 'Test',
    email: 'test@test.se',
    name: 'Test',
    __v: 0,
    posts: [],
    facebook: 
      { token: 'TOKENNUMBER'
       id: '23123123' } },
    _id: 2d8afa19fbf6 }
```

### Edit

Updated the controller in order to populate the user. It now works.

```
// Post page
router.get('/post', function(req, res){
    Post.find().populate('user').exec(function(err, result) {
        if (err) return console.log(err)
        res.render('posts/post', {posts: result});
     })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make a reference to your user in your post Schema, you need to tell *Mongoose* to [populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) the user. If you don't, you'll get only the ObjectId reference to the user in your query result.

```
req.db.collection('posts')
  .find()
  .populate('user')
  .toArray((err, result) => {
    // logic here
})
```

I don't think *ejs* has something to do with this as it is only the render engine.

In your insert, you probably send all the user info, but I'm not really sure because you do not show us full code of your insert query.

Comment: You are right. I updated my answer to make sure you can see the changes